# How to generate URI and connection for Azure Redis Service with aioredis-py

Tags: python, redis, aioredis

I am trying to switch from the official redis python package (`redis-py`) to the async equivalent `aioredis-py` package.

I currently connect using the official package with:

```py
import redis

redis_client = redis.Redis(
    host="abc",
    port=6380,
    password="def",
    ssl=True,
)

redis_client.ping()  # returns True as expected
```

I am currently getting a connection reset by peer when trying to replicate this with `aioredis`:

```py
async def main():
    #uri_template = redis://{password}@{redis_service_name}.redis.cache.windows.net:{port}
    redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://def@abc.redis.cache.windows.net:6380")
    return await redis.ping()

res = asyncio.run(main())
```

I get a `ConnectionResetError`

Am I doing something wrong?